# How making work eslint-plugin-react-native with Atom?

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, eslint

I try to make the linter work on Atom, but nothing happens :/
(I get used to work with eslint on Atom but for a new React Native project I'm totally stuck ...) I work with linter and linter-eslint packages for Atom.

Thanks for any help :)

Here is my package.json, configured as it is said here:
https://github.com/intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native

```
{
  "name": "RNApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "15.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.32.0"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-native"
  ],
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "react-native/no-unused-styles": 2,
    "react-native/split-platform-components": 2,
    "react-native/no-inline-styles": 2,
    "react-native/no-color-literals": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace this:

```
"ecmaFeatures": {
  "jsx": true
},
```

by this:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  }
},
```